# What is the return type of a scala if statement without else

Tags: scala, types

I made a mistake similar to the following in some Scala code:

```
val someVal:String = if (someX == someY) n
```

In retrospect the mistake is clear to me (it has to assign something to someVal, and if the expression is false, it's probably not going to be a string). I want to know what the value returned would be if the expression is false. My best guess is Unit, or perhaps AnyVal.

Comment: if you look at the compiler error you get when you compile that code, it'll tell you exactly what the type of RHS expression is.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That code will not compile, because for `someVal` to be a String, then each execution path (the `if` and the `else`) would have to return a String.  However since you don't have an `else`, this is impossible and thus won't compile.

The compiler error will be the following, which is indicating that you are returning a `Unit` when you are supposed to return `String`:

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: String
```

That's because what you have is equivalent to this:

```
val someVal: String = if (foo == bar) "Hello World" else ()
```

`()` is the only value of [Unit](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/Unit.html), which is not a valid value for a String type.

In the future you can use the Scala repl and have it tell you the types (just don't specify one):

```
scala> val someVal1 = if (true) "Hello World" 
someVal1: Any = Hello World

val someVal2 = if (false) "Hello World" 
someVal2: Any = ()
```

As you can see the type is `Any` because that is the only common parent between `Unit` and `String`:

[image: Class Hierarchy]

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question... I understand why my code was wrong, I only wanted to know what the return type would be if the statement evaluated to false. This last part I believe you addressed, it would be (), correct?

Comment: The code you have doesn't compile, so it would be impossible to get to the `false` case.  You would have to change to `val someVal1: Any` in which case the value would be `()`

Comment: Using `if` without `else` is a bad practice introducing inference issue

Answer (score 3):

The type of whole if expression will be the smallest common supertype of all branches.

The true path is `String` in your example

A missing else is the same as an empty else, both evaluate to `Unit`.

`Unit` and `String` are in completely separate inheritance trees, (String is `AnyRef` and `Unit` is `AnyVal`) so the type of the whole expression is `Any`, the common super type of all types in Scala.

If the true case resulted in an `AnyVal` type (for example, `Int`) then the type of the whole expression would be `AnyVal`

If the true case evaluated to `Unit` (for example if you just used `println` in the if instead of returning a value) then the type of the expression would be `Unit` which makes sense since both paths have the same type.